# Got approved for oembed but still receiving "your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, oembed

I'm struggling a lot with this API.

I just want my users to be able to embed Facebook & Instagram's post on my website.

I have asked access to the `Oembed Read` permissions.

After 5 days I got, what I think to be, permission to use the `Oembed`
[image: App review details, saying my review was approved]

But when I try to make a request with the Graph API Explorer I keep getting the following response

```json
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) To use 'Oembed Read', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Oembed Read' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10,
    "fbtrace_id": "{fbtrace_id}"
  }
}
```

```
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/instagram_oembed?url={instagram_public_post_url}&access_token={app_access_token}"
```

So, is my review not really approved and I need extra steps ? Or is there a bug and I should contact Meta ? I'm lost and I feel like it's really painful to do all of this just for embed request.

Thank you for your helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the people who could have similar problem with me.

It's because I had the "Facebook Login" product setted up on my application. I created a new one without the Facebook Login. After being approved again it was working well.

Comment: Could you describe how you asked access to the `Oembed Read` feature?
In my case i am not even able to request it because the Request Button is disabled. I tried to make API Calls to get this one successful API Request to enable the Request Button, but still i am not able to Request the `Oembed Read` feature

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO75h.png

Comment: @makkus In my case I didn't have to do anything for having the button activated. But from what I learned about Facebook developer environment I think you should be sure that you don't have any app products setted up to your app. Maybe one of them block the possibility to make the request. Try to create an app from blank and see if you can do it from it.